# Generalized Inclusion Exclusion Formula

Tags: probability

An urn has n-3 green balls and 3 red balls. Draw L balls with replacement. Let B denote the event that a red ball is seen at least once. Find P(B) using the generalized inclusion-exclusion formula with events A-sub-i = {ith draw red}.

Comment: Do you know the inclusion-exclusion principle?It applies for a union of events. Make $B$ a union of events and apply the principle.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the inclusion–exclusion principle here (let alone a generalized one). The probability that no red ball is drawn is

$$
\left(\frac{n-3}n\right)^L\;,
$$

and the probability that at least $1$ red ball is drawn is the complement of this.